# Strings in 2D lists in Python

Tags: python

This is a normal 2D list in python containing what supposed to be white spaces:

```
shape = [
["", "", ""],
["", "", ""],
["", "", ""]]
```

but when printing this array using for loop that's what happens:

```
['', '', '']
['', '', '']
['', '', '']
```

isn't it supposed to show only white space ? How do I remove these single quot marks but leave the commas ?

Comment: what do you mean by saying it contains white spaces? Your initial list contains 9 empty strings. Certainly no white spaces there. Please explain in more detail what you're trying to do.

Comment: there is no error here. you have a 2d list. so each item is a LIST which is what it prints, a list with empy strings. `shape[0]` will contain `['', '', '']` `shape[0][0]` will print nothing as THAT is the empty string

Comment: You will not get `a = [,,]` this kind of list as it is invalid in Python

Comment: all what i want is to print the commas only but nothing in the elements like if  I use print("") to print a space.

Comment: `space` is a string. strings are formatted with quotes. You want to remove quotes and show `space`? There is no such thing in python!

Comment: You don't print a space with print("") you print nothing. Well, technically you print a newline because that's the standard way for Python print statements to terminate

Comment: Maybe explain **why** you're trying to do this, this might help us all understand a bit better **what** you actually want to do.

Comment: i don't want to remove commas i only want theme to print a white space like it does with print

Comment: whatever, i want that nothing to be printed out in my list

Comment: What do you expect your final result to look like and why are you trying to do it? I think you're misunderstanding how print works and that makes it difficult to figure out what you're trying to achieve

Comment: this is a regular tictactoe game and that list the board of the game so generally i am trying to print the general shape

Comment: i except it to be like that :
[   ,    ,   ]
[   ,    ,   ]
[   ,    ,   ]

Comment: @MarkDomino So, my answer?

Comment: @MarkDomino You could display empty spaces like `[["_","_","_"],["_","_","_"],["_","_","_"]]
`

Comment: And do you still expect it to behave like a list or is it literally just to print this out?

Comment: behave and print because later i will be replacing those with "X" and "O" and also these are being printed out with single quots too like that: 
['X' ,'','']

Comment: if you're actually trying to write a tic tac toe game, you may be better of writing a class for the board and overwrite it's `__str__` magic method to print the state of the board as you want it.

Comment: @JohnO i didn't want to complex it. if a user wants to make a move he writes the number of the column and row he wants to play in and then i will be using these numbers to refer to the index of the element in the list he wanted to move to like if he choose 00 the index shape[0][0] will be changed to "X" for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it shows everything there is, to remove it, you need to do some string replacing stuff:

```
print(str(shape).replace("'", '').replace('], [', '],\n ['))
```

Which outputs:

```
[[, , ],
 [, , ],
 [, , ]]
```

Comment: This will be String type. You just change the representaion of the object

Comment: @BlueSheepToken It's impossible to do with `list`

Comment: And converting it to type list gives horrendous answer, I don't think it is achievable what the OP wants.

Comment: this one actually worked but how do i make the lists underneath each other ?

Comment: It is what i excepted. Thank you

Comment: @MarkDomino Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

If it's just about printing something to the screen, you don't need to first create a list, just create a string like this:

```
print("[ , , ]\n[ , , ]\n[ , , ]")
```

Or even

```
print("[ | | ]\n[ | | ]\n[ | | ]")
```

Which I think looks better:

```
[ , , ]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[ , , ]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[ , , ]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

[ | | ]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[ | | ]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[ | | ]
```

Comment: this will do if it's just about printing but the elements of the list will be changed later, this is just the initial look. Thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your lists and replace the quotations with empty spaces

```
for x in shape:
print(str(x).replace("'", ""))
```

Which outputs:

```
[, , ]
[, , ]
[, , ]
```